# How to pass an array between ViewControllers for use in UITableView (name, id)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `LoginViewController` where a user logs in.  Upon doing this details are fetched of `communities` they are in.

These `names` of these `communities` are passed to `ViewController` with this section of code:

```
 let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

 if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
       self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!}

 }
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backHome", sender: self.communitiesArray)
```

and

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

    if segue.identifier == "backHome" {
        let createViewController: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        createViewController.communities = communitiesArray
}
```

A `UITableView` is then used to display the list of communities using this code in `ViewController`:

```
var communities = [String]() 
@IBOutlet weak var communitiesTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.communitiesTableView.delegate = self
    self.communitiesTableView.dataSource = self

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.communities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let title = self.communities[indexPath.row]

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = title

    return cell

}
```

If a user selects a community, this opens a new view controller 'ShowCommunityViewController` and passes a variable containing its name:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   self.selectedCellTitle = self.communities[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCommunitySegue", sender: self)
    }
```

However, I also want to pass the `'id'` of this community which is also contained within `"communities"` alongside `'name'`

I was hoping I could do something like this in my `LoginViewController`:

```
if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
   self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!
   self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $1["id"]! 
   }
 }
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backHome", sender: self.communitiesArray)
```

And then somehow pass both the 'name' and 'id' together from 'ViewController' to my new destination `ShowCommunityViewController`.  But that doesn't exist as Syntax and was just something I made up!

What is the best way to pass the `name` and `id` together?

Comment: You can use Nsuserdefautls if your values remain same

Comment: a user can be part of different communities. But once they are logged in this data will not change - unless they join another whilst logged in.

Comment: Ok, then use userdefaults for it. So when user joins another whilst then you can use synchronise it with new data

Comment: so when the initial API call is made upon logging in, store the full array in UserDefaults, then when I am about to go into the 'ShowCommunity' screen, match the name of the selected community from UITableView with that of the id / name stored in UserDefaults?

Comment: yeah , Now you get it. When user changes community save that data with same key so your new data overrites old one.

Comment: Brilliant! I think I'm better at understanding the logic than the code (I'm very new to Swift)

Comment: Just see concept of userdefaults here https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults. You can access those values anywhere into project

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the two together. i.e.

```
let names = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]! }
let ids = arr.flatMap { $1["id"]! }
let communities = zip(names, ids)
```

Comment: I like the idea of this- I was hoping something like this would be possible but it gives me this error:  Contextual closure type '([String : String]) -> _' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body

Answer (score 0):

Create a model object, like the following:

```
class Community {
  let id: String
  let name: String

  init(id: String, name: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
  }
}
```

Once you have your JSON, create an array of `Community`, instead of just using a `String` array.

```
var communities = [Community]()

if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
 communities = arr.flatMap({ (candidate) -> Community?  in
    guard let id = candidate["id"], let name = candidate["name"] else { return nil }
    return Community(id: id, name: name)
})
}
```

I am not exactly sure where do you have this data. But this should be passed to your vc, where you can select the community.

After this, instead of keeping track of the `selectedCellTitle`, keep track of `selectedCommunity` and assign that to your vc in `prepareforsegue`.

Comment: does the 'class Commuity' have to be set up in a new file? or within the LoginViewController?

Comment: I would suggest to be a new file, so the file is visible in your whole module.

Comment: @RDowns any luck?

Comment: Not had time to try it yet.  As a stop gap I have used cellId = indexPath.row to get the index of the matching id and carried that across in segue to communityId. Then in the second view controller used (comIds[communityId!]) where comIds is the actual IDs. Maybe not great but will do for now.  I'll probably go back and tidy it/do it properly when have more time. Thanks for asking